# Is it a bad idea to have a complete high frequency loop on the top plane of a PCB?

Tags: pcb-design, high-frequency

I'm designing a 6 layer HF PCB with the GND plane on the 2nd layer and a 100MHz frequency oscillator on the board, and I'm wondering if it's a bad idea to have the entire loop path of the oscillator on the top plane.

Doing this would create the lowest impedance path since vias have a lot of inductance but I'm not sure of its potential for EMI.

This is a bad idea, correct?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "loop path of the oscillator" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vias have inductance but it's not much at only 100MMHz

also a ground plane masks the signals in front of it somewhat.

put the loop on the top, but keep the loop area small.